# Get appropriate message on apk download attempt

Tags: nativescript

I allow users to update the app apk file when there's a new version.

```
let download_folder : java.io.File = android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS );

let file = fileModule.path.join( download_folder.getPath(), "app.apk" );

permissions.requestPermission( ["android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"], "Permission required to install app update!" )
```

When the user tries to download, they get a system prompt:

`Allow <app-name> to access photos, media, and files on your device?`

Understandably, some users have questioned why the app needs access to photos - I'm just downloading the file and installing it.

I've got the following permissions in the manifest file - but I don't think newer OSes use these.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

What can be done so that they don't get that message?

I've got a message but it seems to be overrridden.

Thanks.

Comment: In general external storage is used to read / write photos, media / files as the permission dialog reads. You can not modify the message shown in the dialog. If you intend to write files to specific directory you could use [Shared Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared) with native APIs.

Comment: I'm writing to `android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` - isn't that public.

Comment: I'm not sure what's your point here, but if you want to convince the users you will just have to show a dialog before invoking permissions, which will explain what's about to happen. You can not change the permission message for sure.

Comment: I'm requesting permission to write to the downloads folder - why does Android need to ask for permissions to the photo folder. users get concerned about permissions like that. I just need a temp scratch area to store a file.

Comment: As I said that's simply how its designed and things are changed in Android 10. Using Shared Storage is optional in Android 10 and it will become mandatory in near future. Refer official android guidelines for more info.